# Lravel 5.1 How to find database records through a from?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, search, laravel-5.1

In the admin area of my app, I want to have a form by which an admin can find a project by its id and show the project details there. What is the best approach to implement this?
This is what I have tried:

```
//route
Route::get('admin/projects/{project_id}', 'AdminController@showProject');
//form
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'AdminController@showProject', 'method' => 'get']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('project_id', 'Project Id', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('project_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}

//controller method
public function showProject(Request $request)
    {
        $project=Project::find($request->get('project_id'));
        return view('admin.projects.showProject', compact('project'));
    }
```

It almost worked but there is little problem. After retrieving the requested project, the ULR is like this:

```
admin/projects/%7Bproject_id%7D?project_id=5
```

I want it be like this one:

```
admin/projects/5
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @ThomasSnijder I edited the question.

Comment: Add your showProject part of the controller where you retrieve the project, I think something is going wrong there.

Comment: @ThomasSnijder I added the contoller method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the following routes:

```
Route::get('admin/projects', 'AdminController@getProject');
Route::post('admin/projects', 'AdminController@postProject');
Route::get('admin/projects/{project_id}', 'AdminController@showProject');
```

In your getProject function you return a view that show the form where the user can enter an ID. (The one you already have):

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'AdminController@postProject', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
    {!! Form::label('project_id', 'Project Id', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('project_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In your postProject function you just send a redirect to admin/project/{project_id} URL:

```
public function postProject(Request $request)
{
    return redirect('admin/projects/' . $request->project_id);
}
```

In your showProject function you just retrieve the record and return a view with the information:

```
public function showProject($ProjectID)
{
    $project=Project::find($ProjectID);
    return view('admin.projects.showProject'),
        ->with('Project', compact('project'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your controller method to

```
 public function showProject($project_id)
{
    $project=Project::find($project_id);
    return view('admin.projects.showProject', compact('project'));
}
```

You don't need to use request on get route.

Comment: The solution you have accepted it's identical though.